# Error in C++/CLI, Can't take address of function unless creating delegate instance using Pthread

Tags: windows, visual-c++, c++-cli, pthreads

I'm using C++/CLI on Visual C++ 2008 Professional, and since I'm using Windows Forms that means I have managed code and I'm trying to call the static function LoginAccounts, but I get an error probably because I'm mixing Managed with Unmanaged Code, but I can't figure out what to do though. I'm using PThread for Windows

```
System::Void testing_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, &Contas::LoginAccounts, this); //Error in this line
}
```

> Error 13  error C3374: can't take address of 'Tester::Test::LoginAccounts' unless creating delegate instance

what do I do to solve this?
It's probably a simple solution, but I can't figure out.
Thanks in advance.

```
 void LoginAccounts(){
    this->btn_next->Enabled = false;
    this->login_accounts->Enabled = false; //Unhandled exception here
     if(this->clb_contas->CheckedItems->Count <= 0){ //Unhandled exception here
         } 

}

System::Void testing_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    ThreadStart^ start = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Login::LoginAccounts);
                Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(start);
                t->Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's just no point in using pthreads if all you want to do is call managed code.  Use the System::Threading::Thread class instead.  You still need to create the delegate that the error message is complaining about, delegates are the managed equivalent of a function pointer.  With bells on, they don't just store the function address but also wrap the object pointer.  Make the code look similar to this:

```
using namespace System::Threading;
...
private: 
    void LoginAccounts() {
        // etc...
    }
    System::Void testing_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        ThreadStart^ start = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::LoginAccounts);
        Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(start);
        t->Start();
    }
```

Note how LoginAccounts() is an instance method here, no need to do the hokeypokey with the *this* reference.

If you really, really want to use pthreads then use Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() to convert the delegate to a pointer that you can pass to native code.  Watch out, you have to keep the delegate object referenced yourself.  The garbage collector cannot see references held by native code.  And you still can't pass *this* without pinning.  These are very ugly details that you can avoid by simply using the Thread class instead.

Comment: "Watch out, you have to keep the delegate object referenced yourself." This can be achieved in C++/CLI with the `gcroot` template.

Comment: I put  as you suggested me managed thread, but I got an error using "this->", I editted my question to show you the error I get using this-> inside of the function called by the thread.

Comment: @AlexandreC. do you think maybe this is why I get an error using this-> inside the function called by the Thread? if yes, how do I solve this ?

Comment: I'll guess you got an InvalidOperationException.  Don't make us guess.  You cannot directly access controls in a worker thread, the UI is not thread-safe.  Only use the thread to perform the slow code, the stuff that isn't UI related.  Whatever that may be.

Comment: but the thing is, I make HTTP requests inside that function, and the program gets frozen until the request is done because it is using the same thread as the UI window, and the data I receive I need to set inside a ListBox (UI)

Comment: The BackgroundWorker class was specifically designed to handle this scenario.  You can use its ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted events to update the UI.  At this point you really ought to pick up a book about Winforms programming.  These kind of scenarios are always well covered.  Trial and error programming is going to be a *lot* of error, threading just isn't a very intuitive concept.  Such a book will explain delegates as well.

Comment: Hans, I really want to learn WinForms from a book, which one would you recommend me? Cause I want to know how to do those BackgroundWorker things. Thanks!

Comment: Type "winforms books" in the search box at the upper right corner of this page.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to your another question at [Calling PThread from Windows Form Class to a function inside the Windows Form Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955632/calling-pthread-from-windows-form-class-to-a-function-inside-the-windows-form-cl/9957566#9957566) You can use the same principle detailed there.